# Modal not loading after filtering

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

**Context**: e-commerce training project

**Using**: PHP and JQuery

**Issue**: Jquery script to display modal is called on page load but not after refreshing part of the page

When I first load my page, I have a button (icon) which, when clicked, loads a modal (description of the item selected). If I subsequently filter the items on the page ( this reloads the  element containing the items), clicking on the button to load the modal does not work any more. The JQuery script is not called (I added an alert to debug). Note: if the first action on loading the page is to refresh the product list and click on the eye, it does NOT work either.

If I look at the page source immediately after first loading and again after reloading the product list, they are identical (using Notepad++ compare function), so I think it's a case of the Java script becoming disabled when an AJAX request is sent to reload the  ?

I think the easiest way to illustrate is with the site itself. Hopefully it's not against the rules

http://pickarooney.sytes.net/__NEW/shop-grid.php

Mouse over a product and click the eye. An alert appears and a modal displays
Then filter by clicking on a category or brand or clicking on the refresh icon beside the search bar
The alert/modal no longer display when the eye icon is clicked.

The script called by the eye icon is this one:

```
        $(".ti-eye").click(function(event) {
            var searchCode = event.target.id.replace("mod", "");
            $.ajax({
                url:"searchproduct.php",    //the page containing php script
                type: "post",    //request type,
                data: {searchCode: searchCode},
                dataType: 'text',
                success:function(result){
                    alert("OK");
                    $("#productmodal").html(result);
                    $("#productmodal").modal('toggle');
                }
            });
        });
```

example of script called when a category filter is applied

```
        $(".cat").click(function(event) {
            var searchCat = event.target.id.replace("cat", "");
            $.ajax({
                url:"searchproduct.php",    //the page containing php script
                type: "post",    //request type,
                data: {searchCat: searchCat},
                dataType: 'text',
                success:function(result){
                    $("#product-grid").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: You should bind events using on instead of directly click. $('#whatever').on('click' ...

Comment: it makes no difference using on $(".ti-eye").on("click", function(event) { 
not sure why the question is closed as none of the answers in the duplicate question work

Comment: @pickarooney you need to use the delegated version of `on()`, not just `on('click', fn)`. In your case it will be `$(document).on('click', '.ti-eye', function(event) {...` and `$(document).on('click', '.cat', function(event) {...`

Comment: that doesn't work at all, even on first page load

Comment: sorry, I missed a bracket when I moved it outside of the document.ready section. Works now! brackets and braces would drive you nuts.